# VB6 to .Net Interface - what is the VB6 datatype for a long?

Tags: .net, interface, interop

I have a .Net object with a method and an interface.
The interface expect one of the parameters to be of type long.
The problem is that Long by vb6 is not Long by .net. it's not the same length, so My vb6 program can't call my .net object now.
I can't break the interface in .net to make this change to int because all the clients that use it will suffer from it.

Any creative Ideas?

TY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent.  Your dilemma is discussed and solutions given here:

http://www.thescarms.com/vbasic/vb6vsvbnet.aspx

> Most APIs that take numeric arguments
>   expect 32-bit values. In VB6 that's a
>   Long data type. In VB.NET a long is
>   64-bits and will not work with 32-bit
>   API calls. Your .NET API parameters
>   will have to be changed or cast to the
>   Integer data type prior to invoking
>   the API.
>
> Many APIs will no longer be callable
>   from VB and others will have
>   replacements. Some that pass strings
>   will need tweaking to pass the correct
>   string or Null value. Check the VB.NET
>   Help for more information.
>
> APIs will need to be handled on a case
>   by case basis. Your best bet is to
>   isolate all your API calls so changes
>   only need to be made in a single
>   location in your code. The upgrade
>   tool will attempt to convert API calls
>   by creating wrappers for them.
>   However, manual intervention will be
>   required.

Answer (score 2):

Without further details, the short answer is that you wrap the .NET object in another one that takes a parameter that you *can* pass from VB6, and then converts it to `long` as needed when calling the method on the existing object.

Only the program in question would need to use the wrapper/new interface; the existing interface stays intact for all other systems.